# Swift detecting where a touch occurs in draw:

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Apologies in advance this is my first time posting a question and I am a beginner to this language but have scraped the forums and documentation already;

type of drawing I would like to create, click to view

[image]

If I was to create a graph similar to the photo attached, is there a way I can execute a function based on what segment that was tapped.

Is there a way to add sender tags to shapes created in draw,
Such as

```
// In custom drawing class
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let shape1 = UIBezierPath() // code for segment 1
    let shape2 = UIBezierPath() // code for segment 2
    let shape3 = UIBezierPath() // code for segment 3
    // etc, etc
    shape1.tag = 1
    shape2.tag = 2
    shape3.tag = 3
    // etc
}

// In ViewController.swift
@IBAction func shapeButtonFunction(_ shape: Any) {
    if shape.tag == 0 {
        // do this
    }
    else if shpae.tag == 1 {
        // do this
    }
}
```

In essence, can I create closed shapes and determine when they were tapped through the use of some kind of tag that can be recognised.

Thank you so much for any help in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIBezierPath has 'contains' method.

[func contains(_ point: CGPoint) -> Bool](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624345-contains)

So, save your shapes and test hit using this method inside touchesBegan or touchesEnded.

```
class   SomeV: UIView {
    var shape1 = UIBezierPath()
    var shape2 = UIBezierPath()
    var shape3 = UIBezierPath()
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        shape1 = UIBezierPath() // code for segment 1
        shape2 = UIBezierPath() // code for segment 2
        shape3 = UIBezierPath() // code for segment 3
        // etc
    }
    override func
    touchesEnded( _ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent? ) {
        if let w = touches.first?.location( in: self ) {
            if shape1.contains( w ) { print( "Touches in shape1" ) }
            if shape2.contains( w ) { print( "Touches in shape1" ) }
            if shape3.contains( w ) { print( "Touches in shape1" ) }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you very very much for your answer and quick response time!